Martingale and Deviance residuals in parametric recurrent event analysis?
I'm developing a nonlinear joint model in which the survival part consists of a parametric time-to-event model that describes a recurrent event process. In this parametric RTTE part I'm directly modelling the hazard, rather than the failure times. The time-origins of the model are specified as follows: The dataset contains the start of the follow-up period and the exact event times for every ID (without any resets). Only one model is specified to describe the RTTE process and a differential equation is used to integrate the hazard function. The cumulative hazard is stored at the time of an event and substracted from the cumulative hazard at the time of a subsequent event (or censoring) to compute the survival and likelihood contribution of that subsequent event (which I figure would be equivalent to setting time = 0 for each individual at an event).
In the process of evaluating the "goodness-of-fit" of developed models, I will primarily be looking at the AIC in combination with simulation-based diagnostics & comparisons with smoothed hazard functions. In addition, I plan to supplement these with residuals such as the modified Cox-Snell, Martingale & Deviance. For these last two, I plan to develop plots vs. survival times and explanatory variables, as per Modelling Survival Data in Medical Research by Collett (4th edition, section 7.2.4). I am unsure whether my understanding of how to compute the Martingale and Deviance residuals in this situation is correct and was hoping that somebody could provide guidance on this matter. From Therneau et al. (1990), the Martingale residual is in my case given as:
$$
\hat{M}_i(t) = N_i(t) - \int_{0}^{t} Y_i(s)d\hat{\Lambda_i}(s),
$$
Since for every time t the $E[\hat{M}_i(t)] = E[\hat{M}_i(t-1)] = 0$, would it be appropriate to compute $\hat{M}_i(t)$ for every event/censoring time, so that model accuracy can be evaluated based on all of the recorded event times? If yes, what would be the "best" way of computing the $\hat{M}_i(t)$ here:

Based on intervals spanning from $[t-1, t]$?
Or on intervals spanning from $[0,t]$?

Where t-1 and t are the previous and current event times, respectively. Or would this depend on the question we are trying to answer with our model (i.e. go for $[t-1,t]$ if accurate prediction of the time between events n-1 and n is of importance)?
Then for the deviance residuals, Therneau et al. (1990) present these for the Cox model as follows:
$$
d_i = \operatorname{sgn}(\hat{M}_i) \left[ -2\{ \hat{M}_i + \delta_i \log (\delta_i - \hat{M}_i)\} \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
Is there a way to transform these to the "longitudinal" setting (i.e. for every recorded time rather than based on the $\hat{M}_i$ that are computed over the complete follow-up period for every individual i)? And, on a related note, is there much to gain from computing the $d_i$ alongside the $\hat{M}_i$ in the case of recurrent events? Given that the $d_i$ were developed to achieve a more normal shaped distribution of residuals, which seems to be less of an issue for in the case of recurrent events due to the possible range of values $\hat{M}_i$ can take on (theoretically $[-\infty,\infty]$ in my case).
To provide some context to my questions: This paper, introducing the deviance residual in my field of research proposes to compute the deviance residual using $\hat{M}_i(t)$ based on intervals spanning from $[t-1, t]$, and only for observed event times. I'm uncertain how appropriate this is, considering that we discard the censored part of the data using this approach. It's also the only example I could find where $\hat{M}_i$ was derived for multiple times within each individual, as other studies like this one and this one, only compute the $\hat{M}_i$ and $d_i$ based on an interval of $[0, t_{max}]$.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit the question to say more about how you plan to use the martingale/deviance residuals to evaluate your parametric model. They have some important uses, but in practice they can turn out to be less helpful than one might hope. Please say more about the type of parametric model you are building; for accelerated failure time models there are good ways to use other residuals. Also, please describe the choice of time origins for the model: do you reset to time=0 for each individual at an event, or do you have different models for subsequent events?

Hi @EdM, thanks for the welcome! I edited the post so you may find the answers to most of your questions there. If more details are necessary, please let me know and I'll make sure to provide them! I am indeed aware of the fact that the usefulness of these residuals is limited, hence my decision to only use them as supplement to other diagnostics. Still, I was hoping that they would provide some value in terms of comparing the performance between models/identifying influential covariates.

With a joint covariate/event model over time you presumably have time-varying outcome-associated covariates. Unless the instantaneous hazard in your parametric model is related to current covariate values, as it is in proportional hazards (PH) models but not generally in accelerated failure time (AFT) models, the martingale residuals* and their transformations into deviance residuals might not be very useful. See Section 2 of this vignette from the R eha package for how AFT models depend on the entire covariate history. Plots of martingale residuals to evaluate the functional form of a covariate thus are troublesome in AFT models: which value of a time-varying covariate will you use?
As Section 7.1.3 of your reference explains, a martingale residual is the difference between the event indicator and the Cox-Snell (possibly censored) residual at an observation time. Overall model fit can be evaluated by Cox-Snell residuals or, for AFT models, the related (censored) standardized residuals. Section 18.3 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies shows how to use censored standardized residuals to evaluate an AFT model. There isn't much use for martingale/deviance residuals beyond that for evaluation of the model, with some exceptions noted below.
To answer the question, more or less in reverse order:
Your sense is correct that martingale/deviance residuals should include both event and censoring times. Otherwise you lose the information provided by censored event times. I'm not familiar with the 1999 paper you cite, or why the authors might have chosen otherwise.
The deviance residuals are transformed versions of the martingale residuals, and were designed to help identify individual outliers rather than overall model quality. There probably isn't much you can learn from them that won't be obvious from the martingale residuals. In Section 4.3 of Modeling Survival Data, Therneau and Grambsch say:

The deviance residual was designed to improve on the martingale residual for revealing individual outliers, particularly in plotting applications. In practice it has not been as useful as anticipated.

If you want to evaluate whether some individuals are outliers, you might use martingale residuals from the full model at the last observation times, over $[0,t_{max}]$. That summarizes the overall lack of fit to your recurrent-event data for that individual.
If instantaneous hazard is a function of current covariate values, martingale residuals might be used to evaluate the functional form of a continuous covariate. You might plot martingale residuals against covariate values from a null model (or one with all other covariates included) to get an idea of the functional form. Or, given a particular model, you could see whether a smoothed plot of martingale residuals against the covariate's values was reasonably flat.
For those purposes, with time-varying covariates you would want to evaluate the residual at an observation time (event or censoring) based on the period of time when the current covariate value was in place: with counting-process data that would be over $[t-1,t]$ in your terminology. It seems that most of your observations will be (recurrent) event times rather than censoring, so you probably won't have the substantial banding at negative residual values seen when there's a lot of censoring or when counting-process data have at most a single event (Section 5.1.3 of Therneau and Grambsch). Section 5.6 of Therneau and Grambsch provides some cautions, however, about use of martingale residuals with time-varying covariates.
Even if a plot of martingale residuals suggest a functional form for the association between a continuous predictor and outcome, you will still have to go back to re-fit the data accordingly. It's typically more efficient to let the data tell you the functional form directly, with a regression spline, smoothing spline, or other generalized additive model. See Sections 5.4 and 5.5 of Therneau and Grambsch. If you do that, you might document the success of fitting the functional form by showing that a smoothed plot of full-model martingale residuals against the predictor is reasonably flat.

*Section 7.1.3 of your reference notes: "Strictly speaking, it is no longer appropriate to refer to these residuals as martingale residuals since the derivation of them, based on martingale methods, does not carry over to the accelerated failure time model."

Thanks for the insightful and extremely detailed response @EdM. I'm still wondering though, may any useful inference be gained from plots of the Martingale residuals vs. the event times, as suggested by Collett (i.e. to identify influential observations, rather than individuals)? Intuitively, it seems like these could provide (potentially limited, due to censoring & covariate effects) guidance in assessing the shape of the hazard in parametric (PH) modelling, as well as possibly inspire the evaluation of specific (time-varying) covariates based on clinical/disease-related knowledge.

@AhmedW Maybe, but I'd focus on the outliers by individuals (over all of an individual's observations) first. One thing I didn't discuss is the correlation of observations within individuals; see Chapter 8 of Therneau and Grambsch. I suspect that "outliers" in observations will be concentrated in individuals who are "outliers" overall. That might represent an individual-associated "frailty" that you could incorporate into your model. That said, it won't hurt to try observation-specific residuals despite my skepticism.
